# Updating Db table from asp.net Details View that has Cascading dropdown lists

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net

As my title says, I have an asp.net Details view. Within the view are 3 dropdown lists that cascade. The 'cascading' works fine, but the data is not being updated in the sql db. The following is the code:

```
        <asp:DetailsView ID="detailEmpChange" runat="server" AutoGenerateRows="False" DataKeyNames="empChangePrcID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2">
        <Fields>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="empChangePrcID" HeaderText="empChangePrcID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="empChangePrcID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="empChangeID" HeaderText="empChangeID" SortExpression="empChangeID" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="empNum" SortExpression="empNum">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("empNum") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("empNum") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="reportsToEmpNum" SortExpression="reportsToEmpNum">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlReportsTo" runat="server" DataSourceID="sdsReportsTo" DataTextField="ReportsTo" 
                        DataValueField="ReportsToEmpNum" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("reportsToEmpNum") %>' AutoPostBack="true" 
                        OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlReportsTo_SelectedIndexChanged">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="sdsReportsTo" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SecondDb %>" 
                        SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT [ReportsToEmpNum], [ReportsTo] FROM [tblEmployees] ORDER BY [ReportsTo]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("reportsToEmpNum") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="dept" SortExpression="dept">
                <EditItemTemplate> <%--SelectedValue='<%# Bind("dept")%>' tried this but got error --%>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDept" runat="server" DataSourceID="sdsDept" DataTextField="dept" 
                        DataValueField="dept" AutoPostBack="true" AppendDataBoundItems="false" 
                        OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlDept_SelectedIndexChanged">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="sdsDept" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SecondDb %>" 
                        SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT [Organizational Unit] AS dept FROM [tblEmployees] 
                        WHERE ([ReportsToEmpNum] = @ReportsToEmpNum) ORDER BY dept">
                        <SelectParameters>
                            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlReportsTo" Name="ReportsToEmpNum" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
                        </SelectParameters>
                    </asp:SqlDataSource>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("dept") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="job" SortExpression="job">
                <EditItemTemplate><%--SelectedValue='<%# Bind("job") %>'  tried this but got error --%>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlJob" runat="server" DataSourceID="sdsJob" DataTextField="Job1" 
                        DataValueField="Job" AutoPostBack="false" AppendDataBoundItems="false" >
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="sdsJob" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SecondDb %>" 
                        SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT [Job], [Job1] FROM [tblEmployees] 
                        WHERE ([Organizational Unit] = @dept) AND (ReportsToEmpNum = @ReportsToEmpNum) ORDER BY [Job1]">
                        <SelectParameters>
                            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlDept" Name="dept" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="string" />
                            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlReportsTo" Name="ReportsToEmpNum" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
                        </SelectParameters>
                    </asp:SqlDataSource>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("job") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
        </Fields>
    </asp:DetailsView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MainDb %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [tblEmpChange] WHERE ([empChangePrcID] = 7)" 
        UpdateCommand="UPDATE [tblEmpChange] SET [reportsToEmpNum] = @reportsToEmpNum, [reportsToName] = @reportsToName,  [dept] = @dept, 
            [deptDesc] = @deptDesc, [job] = @job, [job1] = @job1 WHERE [empChangePrcID] = @empChangePrcID">
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="reportsToEmpNum" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="reportsToName" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="dept" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="deptDesc" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="job" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="job1" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="empChangePrcID" Type="Int32" />
        </UpdateParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

And here is the vb code:

```
Protected Sub ddlReportsTo_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
       Dim dscD As SqlDataSource = detailEmpChange.FindControl("sdsDept")

       Dim ddl1 As DropDownList = detailEmpChange.FindControl("ddlReportsTo")
       Dim ddl2 As DropDownList = detailEmpChange.FindControl("ddlDept")

       ddl2.Items.Clear()
       dscD.SelectParameters(0).DefaultValue = ddl1.SelectedValue
       ddl2.DataBind()

       ddl2.Items.Insert(0, New ListItem("- Select -"))
   End Sub

   Protected Sub ddlDept_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

       Dim dscJC As SqlDataSource = detailEmpChange.FindControl("sdsJob")

       Dim ddl1 As DropDownList = detailEmpChange.FindControl("ddlReportsTo")
       Dim ddl2 As DropDownList = detailEmpChange.FindControl("ddlDept")
       Dim ddl3 As DropDownList = detailEmpChange.FindControl("ddlJob")

       ddl3.Items.Clear()
       dscJC.SelectParameters(0).DefaultValue = ddl1.SelectedValue
       dscJC.SelectParameters(1).DefaultValue = ddl2.SelectedValue
       ddl3.DataBind()

       ddl3.Items.Insert(0, New ListItem("- Select -"))
   End Sub
```

Can anybody see what I am missing or that's wrong? I am using data from two different Db but they are on the same server. Basically I am loading the details view from a table in the MainDb, and then loading options for the ddls from a table in the SecondDb. The update should update the table in the MainDb with the newly selected values from the ddls in the details view. Hope that's enough info for someone.

Let me know, and thanks for reviewing this!

Comment: Have you debugged your code? If not, you need to do that first. If so, you need to explain exactly where and how the behaviour of the code differs from your expectation.

Comment: Yes I have debugged. There are no errors. The difference from my expectation is that when I click the Update link within the details view, the ddls are not updating the table in the sql Db with the selected data, it is updated with the value "NULL".

Comment: That's a difference in the end result, not in the specific behaviour of the code. You haven't debugged properly. Set a breakpoint, step through the code and examine the state at each step. When the actual state differs from the expected state, you have found your issue. If you still can't solve it, at least you can provide us with all the relevant information. If reality never differs from expectation then it's your expectations that are at fault, so you need to re-examine them.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot set breakpoints on the aspx code, only the vb code. And there's no problem with the vb code. Maybe I need to do the update statement in VB instead of an  'asp:SqlDataSource'? I'll try that and post my result.

Comment: No luck on the VB update statement either. I tested using a telerik radgrid but could not get that to work. In my original code I am able to update the some of the fields in the database. One problem I'm working on now is to pre-populate the DDLs with the current value from the table. The usual Selectedvalue='<%# Bind("dept")%>' throws an error: 'ddlDept' has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items. Any ideas out there? Thanks.